# Extract image from main content area in PowerPoint slide to re-enable grouping

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint

PowerPoint has an annoying feature where images pasted into the main content area of the slide cannot be grouped with other objects.

This is the main content area:

[image]

For this reason I never use the main content area for single images anymore. However, I have some old PowerPoint slides where images are inserted into this main area. I would like to re-use these, but the inability to group makes it impossible.

How can I disassociate an already pasted image from the main content area, short of just making a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Select the image, press Command+C to copy it.

Press DEL to delete it.

The placeholder will revert to its starting state (as shown in your screenshot). If you no longer need it, select it again and DEL to delete it.

If you DO need to use it for something else, click it and type some junk text; anything to temporarily "fill" the placeholder so it doesn't grab your image again.

Finally, choose Paste Special, as PNG/JPG or whatever's most appropriate and paste in the image you copied in the first step.